# hg bundle revset - not change found

Tags: mercurial

We are trying to bundle part of a repository.

The following command: `hg bundle -r 1:11 bundle.hg` produces the output "Searching for changes. No change found".

If we reuse the same revset with another command, `hg log -r 1:11` the expected list of changesets is displayed.

Using `hg bundle -a bundle.hg` works fine.

Using HG 3.8.4 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [hg bundle's documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/bundle), there is the following paragraph:

> To create a bundle containing all changesets, use -a/--all (or --base null). Otherwise, hg assumes the destination will have all the nodes you specify with --base parameters. Otherwise, hg will assume the repository has all the nodes in destination, or default-push/default if no destination is specified.

It reads a little bit like a nested if-statement, so let me paraphrase it.

- If you specify `-a` or `--all` (or `--base null` on its own), you'll bundle all the changesets
- If you haven't specified `-a` or `--all`, you can specify which nodes are present at the destination using `--base`
- If you've done neither of the above, Mercurial assumes the changesets present at the specified destination, if any, or default-push/default

Your attempt, `hg bundle -r 1:11 bundle.hg`, is in the last category, and I suspect that all nodes in the revset are present at default-push/default.

Try amending your command to `hg bundle -r 1:11 --base null bundle.hg`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Doing 'hg bundle --base null -r 1:50 bundle_1.hg' does run without error and produces a file smaller than using --all switch. However, running hg bundle --base null -r 40:50 bundle_2.hg produces a file which is binary equal to bundle_1.hg. I am guessing using --base null is causing the issue. This makes me think that mixing --base and --rev can cause conflicts and maybe it is not a good idea.

Comment: Or, `--base null` says there's nothing at the destination, so seems to  bundle all pre-cursors. Can you try `--base ancestors(40:50) -r 40:50` instead?

Comment: I then get 'no changes found' message in shell. Tried using ancestor(40:50) and the produced '10 changesets found'

Comment: So using ancestor(40:50) appears to work but will try some more example tomorrow. Not sure

Comment: May I take a step backwards and ask you to clarify what you are trying to achieve? Although it the above command will bundle only 40:50, they will make little sense without the context of ancestors. Are the ancestors present on the system where you want to unbundle?

Comment: The purpose of the post was to better understand the bundle command which I found a bit confussing when reading the docs. What we would like to achieve is to bundle part of a repository based on date. So basically, bundle all commits that are from 2017-1-1 and newer.

Comment: Bundle those commits to what purpose? and specifically to bundle it? Unbundling in the destination repo fails if the parents (and by extension, ancestors) are not present. So for hg bundle to be useful, you must know what is in your destination. I ask the purpose because I can think of a some possible purposes, but some of them can be better met in alternative ways. E.g. to create a snapshot at a certain date and later commits. Things can also get complicated when there are multiple branches in the subset you're trying to extract.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your mean. We would like to synchronize two repositories that are not connect. Using bundle and unbundle commands we are able to accomplish this task. The current approach bundles the entire repository each time. This is wasteful in terms of time and bundle size. We would like to avoid using bookmarks and tags to label each time we perform a bundle. We would rather like to tell hg to bundle all changesets commited in the last 30 days or since a date (2017-02-01). Obviously the developer is aware and responsible for setting correct date or timeframe.

Comment: The date or timeperiod will depend on multiple factors. We are aware that unbundle fail at remote site if parents are not present.

Comment: In that case, can I suggest setting up a local clone to bundle against? So you want to synchronise repos A and B on different (unconnected) machines. Suppose you set up a clone C of repo B on the same computer as repo A. You should now be able hg bundle repo A against destination C. Then unbundle the changegroup in both B and C. I think that would be simpler to manage (because hg takes care of selecting the minimum set of changesets), in particular with regards to a branchy repo structure. The described setup is one-way, but can easily be extended to a two-way setup.